# Duplicate need of 2d elements python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the index of all of the duplicate items in a 2d list.
I tried so many times but can't write a function to find the indexes of all the duplicate items in the 2d list.
Here is an example of the list:
[[0, 6],[3, 0]]
Please help me to write a program to find the indexes of the 0s in the list

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are looking for this.by using this you can find list two duplicate indexes.

```
a = [[0,6,4],[3,0,4]]

[i for i, item in enumerate(a[1]) if item in a[0] #finding duplicate index

Out[1292]: [1, 2]
```